# How do you change the colors in the Send Message dialog triggered by UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, ios7

I am using the UIActivityViewController to allow the user to send messages in my app.  The issue is that when I choose Message as my share method, the "To:" section inherits the background color of my NavigationBar.

This is only a problem when you choose Message as your method - if you choose Mail, everything below the NavigationBar shows up with a white background.

Here is a screenshot of my issue:

[image]

In my `AppDelegate.m` I have the following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [RMTheme theme].accentLight;
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor    = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

And the activity controller is triggered with the following code:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: how about changing your navigation bar color to white or default right before you push MFMailComposeViewController?

Comment: This did not have any impact

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you are using "PUSH" style when you show your `UIActivityViewController`, instead you should use "Modal" style.

**Storyboard**

[image: Storyboard]

**Code**

```
[yournavigationController presentModalViewController:YourActivityViewController animated:YES];
```

**Solution 2** - Use image

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar3"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Solution 3** - Set bar tint

```
[[self navigationController]navigationBar].barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: I'm using `[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`.  `presentModalViewController` is deprecated; however, when I tried that method, it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Take a look at the solution 2 and 3, you can override the color of the navigation bar with image or tint color. Make sure you reset the color when you dismiss the view.

Comment: You can do this in your activityViewController's ViewDidLoad.

Comment: Right, but I'm not trying to change the color of the navigation bar - I'm trying to change the color of the bar beneath it.

Comment: Can you try changing the activityViewController subview's tintColor? If it is still not working, can you show me your storyboard structure for this controller?